# Problem with adding and removing elements from dynamically added component in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm wondering how to add and remove specific elements from dynamically added sections. I'm fighting with it for a week and can't find the solution for my case.

Problem is clearly described in the images.
To sum up the biggest problem is that the removing buttons don't know to which element they belong.

```
<template>
  <div>

    <div class="section" v-for="(el, index) in sections" :key="index" >
      
      <td>
        SECTION:{{index}}  
        
        <div class="element" v-for="(sel, index) in sections" :key="index">
         <span>PICK UP YOUR ANIMAL</span>
          <select >           
            <option v-for="(item, index) in zoo" :key="index" v-bind:value="item">
              <option>{{item.name}}</option>
            </option>          
          </select>
          <button class="rem el" @click='removeElement(index, el)'>-</button> 
        
        </div>
      
      </td> 
      
      <button  class="addEleme" @click='addElement'>add element</button> 
      <button class="rem sec" @click='removeSection'>-</button>
   
    </div>
    
    <button class="addSect" @click='addSection'>add section</button>
    <p>{{test}}</p>
    <span>{{sections}}</span>
    <span>{{elements}}</span>
 
  </div>

</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    data() {
      return {
        zoo: [
            {name: "Crocodyle Sara"},
            {name: "Elepfhant Mike"},
            {name: "Lion Monika"},
            {name: "Shark Robert"},
            {name: "Zebra Antony"} 
        ],
        sections:[],
        elements:[],
        test:"",
        i:1
        
      }
    },
    methods:{

// Sections meth   
//----------------------------------------//
      addSection(){
        this.sections.push(this.zoo)
        this.i+=1
        this.test=`gucci: check console`
        console.log('this.sections: ', this.sections);
      },
       removeSection(index){
        this.sections.splice(index, 1)
        this.test="remove section"  
      },

// Elemnts meth       
//----------------------------------------//
      addElement(){
        this.test=`not gucci: should add element`
      },
      removeElement(index){
        this.elements.splice(index, 1)
        this.test="not gucci should remove element"
      }

    }
  }
</script>
```

[image: problem explenation]

Answer (score 3):

Take a look in following simple solutions with another component:

```js
Vue.component('mySelect', {
  template: `
    <div>
    <select v-model="selected" @change="selectAnimal"> 
      <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
      <option v-for="(item, index) in zoo" :key="index" v-bind:value="item">
        {{item.name}}
      </option>          
    </select>
    <button class="rem el" @click='remove'>remove element</button>
    </div>
  `,
  props: ['idx', 'el'],
  data() {
    return {
      zoo: [{name: "Crocodyle Sara"}, {name: "Elepfhant Mike"}, {name: "Lion Monika"}, {name: "Shark Robert"}, {name: "Zebra Antony"}],
      selected: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectAnimal() {
      const obj = {id: this.el, ...this.selected}
      this.$emit('sel', obj)
    },
    remove() {
      const obj = {idx: this.idx, el: this.el}
      this.$emit('rem', obj)
    }
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      sections: [],
      selected: []
    }
  },
  methods:{
    newId() {
      return Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
    },
    addSection(){
      this.sections.push({id: this.newId(), elements: [this.newId()]})
    },
    removeSection(index){
      this.sections.splice(index, 1) 
    },
    addElement(idx){
      const nr = this.sections[idx].elements.length
      this.sections[idx].elements.push(this.newId())
    },
    removeElement(obj){
      const elems = this.sections[obj.idx].elements
      const element = elems.find(e => e === obj.el)
      this.selected = this.selected.filter(f => f.id !== element)
      this.sections[obj.idx].elements = elems.filter(e => e !== element)
    },
    handleSelect(sel) {
      const found = this.selected.find(s => s.id === sel.id)
      this.selected = this.selected.map(x => (x.id === sel.id) ? sel : x)
      if (!found) this.selected.push(sel)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <ul class="section" v-for="(section, index) in sections" :key="index" >
      SECTION:{{section.id}}  
      <li class="element" v-for="(element, idx) in section.elements" :key="idx">
        <span>PICK UP YOUR ANIMAL {{element}}</span>
        <my-select :el="element" :idx="index" @sel="handleSelect" @rem="removeElement"></my-select>
      </li>
    <button class="addEleme" @click='addElement(index)'>add element</button> 
    <button class="rem sec" @click='removeSection(index)'>remove section</button>
  </ul>
  <button class="addSect" @click='addSection'>add section</button>
  <p>Sections: {{ sections }}</p>
  <p>Selected: {{ selected }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you i will study your proprosition. But all ready checked that in your solution you can remove elements only  from end of the list, not form middle.

Comment: @Jane Jacek hey, NO you remove elements you want, from start, middle, end, doesn't metter, watch id's in sections array, also watch selected array it's also updated :)

Comment: @Jane Jacek look again pls, check ID of elements when you remove

Comment: You're right ! My ignorance. With out id's I'v focused on selected velues. Thanks a lot

Comment: Now I see the problem. It's not posible to delate particular section, only the first one.

Comment: check now pls I updated answer :)

Comment: Got it thank you so much